# Background color not displaying in Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an issue where code in IE shows color formatting correctly, but when using Firefox, it does not.

I've tried to use Firebug, I can see where the cells are and that the "style" gets loaded correctly, but it just doesn't display the background color in Firefox...

Relevant code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Internal Radiant Support - Agent Stats</title>

<!-- Stylesheet -->            
<style type="text/css">
table.default {
    empty-cells:hide;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    empty-cells:hide;
}

table.default th {
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
}

table.default td {
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="100%" text="#000000" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
<form action="" method="post" name="crs_form" style="margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
<table align="center" class="default">
<tr class="default">
<th><input type="submit" name="agent_stats_PC[calendar][navigate][previous]" value="<"></th>
<th colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="agent_stats_PC[calendar][navigate][month]" value="February"><input type="submit" name="agent_stats_PC[calendar][navigate][month]" value="2013"></th>
<th><input type="submit" name="agent_stats_PC[calendar][navigate][next]" value=">"></th>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<th width="35">S</th>
<th width="35">M</th>
<th width="35">T</th>
<th width="35">W</th>
<th width="35">T</th>
<th width="35">F</th>
<th width="35">S</th>
<th width="35">W</th>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<td style="align=center; background-color=#C4C4C4;">27</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>31</td>
<td>01</td>
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">02</td>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">03</td>
<td>04</td>
<td>05</td>
<td>06</td>
<td>07</td>
<td>08</td>
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">09</td>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">10</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">16</td>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">17</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>22</td>
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">23</td>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<td style="align=center; background-color=#C4C4C4;">24</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>01</td>
<td style="align=center; background-color=#E4E4E4;">02</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /><table align="center" class="default">
<tr class="default">
<th>Agent Stats Converter</th>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<td><textarea name="agent_stats_PC[import][data]" cols="32" rows="8"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr class="default">
<th><input type="submit" name="agent_stats_PC[import][button]" value="Submit"><input type="submit" name="agent_stats_PC[import][button]" value="Cancel"></th>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mix up css in tags and in the css area - but that is not the problem.

If you mean this part:

```
<td style="align=center; background-color=#C4C4C4;">27</td>
```

then it is

```
<td style="text-align:center; background-color:#C4C4C4;">27</td>
```

: is css, = is used like this:

```
<td background="..." ...
```